# Using .Fortran() from R package with error saying function not available

Tags: r, fortran, quantreg

I tried the following codes:

```
library(quantreg) # to load the package
library(foreign)  # to load the package

.Fortran("rqfn", PACKAGE = "quantreg")
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in .Fortran("rqfn", PACKAGE = "quantreg") : 
"rqfn" not available for .Fortran() for package "quantreg"
```

I have installed Rtools. But it does not solve the problem. 
I also checked the issues concerning system paths (as in this site: https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Install-Rtools-for-Windows), but there is no problem about that.
Could anyone give me a hand? Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you looked carefully at the source code to see whether that subroutine is still actually used? Is it possible that it has been replaced by other/newer versions with different names?

Comment: Hello,Joran, thank you very much for your help. this "rqfn" function is still in use, as from the package's github page: https://github.com/cran/quantreg/blob/master/src/rqfn.f , however, when I was checking the local directory where this quantreg is installed, I could not find this file!

Comment: The function `rqfn`is not registered, see https://github.com/cran/quantreg/blob/master/src/init.c#L49. Can you use `rqfnb` or `rqfnc`?

Comment: Hello, thank you very much Ralf. I have tried `rqfnb` and `rqfnc`, but the same error message appears in R.

Comment: This is odd. On Linux I also get error messages, but those are like `Incorrect number of arguments (0), expecting 13 for 'rqfnb'`. So it looks usable in principle when supplied with the right number of arguments.

Comment: Thank you... This is really weird.. For me, I always get the same error message. I am so confused.

Comment: On my Windows7, using `.Fortran("rqfnb", PACKAGE = "quantreg")` or `.Fortran("rqfnc", PACKAGE = "quantreg")` I get `Incorrect number of arguments (0), expecting 13 for 'rqfnb'`

Comment: Just because the source file exists doesn't mean it's still being used. The fact that it isn't registered suggests to me that `rqfn.f` may be legacy code. As others have observed, the `rqfnb` and `rqfnc` versions appear to be callable for me as well.

Comment: @ShengBi Is the `quantreg` package correctly installed on your system? Do R functions like `rq.fit.fnb` work?

Comment: @Marco Sandri Thank you very much for your reply. Indeed, for my Win 10, I now arrive at the same message as yours. So the problem is on `rqfn`.

Comment: @joran, Thank you very much Joran. Exactly, that is what I have found.  Unfortunately, I really need `rqfn` for my study.. `rqfnb` and `rqfnc` could not replace its function..

Comment: @Ralf Stubner Thank you very much for your help Stubner! I actually tried a lot of versions of `quantreg`, from the most up-to-date one to to the most ancient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own library:

- Download `rqfn.f` and `rqfnb.f`. The latter is needed for `stepy` method.
- Call `R CMD SHLIB rqfn.f rqfnb.f`
- use the function like this:

  ```
  data(stackloss)
  x <- stack.x
  y <- stack.loss
  n <- length(y)
  p <- ncol(x)
  dyn.load(paste0("rqfn", .Platform$dynlib.ext))

  .Fortran("rqfn",
       as.integer(n),
       as.integer(p),
       a = as.double(t(as.matrix(x))),
       c = as.double(y),
       rhs = double(p),
       d = double(n),
       beta = as.double(0.99995),
       eps = as.double(1e-6),
       tau = as.double(0.5),
       wn = double(10 * n),
       wp = double((p + 3) * p),
       aa = double(p * p),
       it.count = integer(2),
       info = integer(1))
  ```

Comment: Thank you Stubner.... I am really impressed.... To be honest, I do not think I understand  how it works and why it is so... but that is really really nice.. and Thank you very much for your constant concern on my problem..